# Getting Controls From a Page Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I am new to .Net platform and I am stuck in retrieving controls from .aspx pages since two days.

I am trying to get all the `controls` from all the `.aspx` pages in my website.
So for that I create the object of the Page from the string of class name which I get from my database. I have already stored the  `class names` of .aspx.cs files in database

The code in C# is:

```
Page obj = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(null, string ClassName).Unwrap();
```

The string `"ClassName"` is taken from the database.

Now during Debug time I can see that there are `controls` in the `obj` but I get `0` in `controls.count`. I guess this is because the controls are still `not initialized`.

***Image 1 during debug time***[image: Image 1 during debug time]:

***Image 2 during debug time showing my controls***[image: Image 2 during debug time showing my controls]

My code looks like this.

```
Page obj = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(null, string ClassName).Unwrap()
List<string[]> fieldsNotInDB = GetControlCollections(obj)
```

This is my `function` to get all the `controls` from the `Page obj`

```
public List<string[]> GetControlCollections(Page p)
        {

            List<string[]> controlList = new List<string[]>();
            IterateControls(p.Controls, controlList);
            return controlList;
        }
        public void IterateControls(System.Web.UI.ControlCollection page, List<string[]> controlList)
        {
            foreach (System.Web.UI.Control c in page)
            {
                if (c.ID != null)
                {
                    string []s=new string[2];
                    s[0]=c.ID;
                    s[1]=c.GetType().ToString();
                    controlList.Add(s);
                }

                if (c.HasControls())
                {
                    IterateControls(c.Controls, controlList);
                }
            }
        }
```

How do I get the `Controls` from my `obj`?

Comment: As a personal opinion - when using `Activator.CreateInstance(..)` you should be asking yourself "Am I bending the framework *to* hard..?"

Comment: I have one asp page from which I will be selecting other asp pages and then view all the controls in it and assign appropriate rights to it. So for that I need some dynamic way of selecting a page and get its controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a fundamental point of asp.net : the page lifecycle.

Here, you are creating an instance of your page object, and it's the time where the collection are initialised.

But in a real asp.net webforms website, when you reach a page, the asp.net pipeline not only create the instance, but it will also launch a several events attached to the pages (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx)

In fact, the controls of yours page will not be available before the init event.

Comment: So if I call the Init event of the object than I will be able to access all the controls. But I am not able to figure out that how to call the init event from my code.

Comment: At debug time I can see the list of controls present in the object as I have shown in the image. I am not sure but may be the 'Init()' event has been called already.

Comment: thoses controls are properties of your Page, that are by default declared in your [pagename].designer.cs automatically by visual studio when you add the control in your .aspx file.
Your page is instanciated, so you can see the propertizs in the watcher. and as you can see, the properties are null. 
the init() event is called by the asp.net pipeline, and i never tried to call it manually ;)

Comment: Okay.. now I am getting what is happening in the code and page life cycle. Thanks for the help..